# What is the minimal schematic (needed capactiors/resistors) to use FPGA Altera Cyclone 4 EP4CE6E22C8N?

Tags: fpga, wiring, intel-fpga, cyclone

I can't find any information about how wire the Cyclone 4 FPGA.
I do not want to use development boards.

Comment: Most likely: power, decoupling capacitors, program rom and a clock (Xtal).

Comment: Probably a bit less then what is on a DE0 or DE2 board from Terasic... You need to read through the 1000 page data sheet. One usually does not just "wire" an FPGA. You typically need a design started to know if your banks can support everything your trying to do, and to estimate power needs and decoupling needs.

Comment: Look at a dev board schematic and decide what you need and what you don't, that is the easiest way to determine what you need. Otherwise its reading the datasheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically the best way to start with any FPGA design is to find the schematic of a relatively simple commercial development kit, and strip away the various peripherals you don't need. The advantage of this is that somebody has already done a relatively decent job of working out what is required.

You can also start from scratch with the help of various documentation from the FPGA manufacturer. This includes pin-out files, datasheets, and other connection information. In the case of Altera/Intel devices, you can find pin connection guidelines (PCG) [here](https://www.altera.com/documentation/lit-dpcg.html), and package pin-outs [here](https://www.altera.com/support/literature/lit-dp.html).

---

The [Cyclone IV PCG file](https://www.altera.com/content/dam/altera-www/global/en_US/pdfs/literature/dp/cyclone-iv/pcg-01008.pdf) gives you lots of information you will need to know about what each pin does, recommended power supply setups, configuration pin requirements (watch out for pull-up resistors on pins like `CONF_DONE` without which the device won't configure), all in a nice 14-page summary.

After that, make sure you test compile any designs you want to confirm you haven't missed any pin requirements. Do this *before*  you commit to getting a PCB made. It's very easy to choose the wrong pin for something like a clock input, or memory interface, only to find out it won't compile.

Comment: what is the simplest board with schematics included which you recommend me to start?